# Can evolution surge, greater be used for a single evolution?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, eidolon

The language in the spell [evolution surge, greater](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/evolution-surge/) is vague:

> This spell functions as lesser evolution surge (see above), except that you can grant any two evolutions whose total cost does not exceed 6 evolution points.

What I feel is vague is the word *any*. Must two evolutions be selected, or can you choose one evolution and spend all the points on it? I want to use the spell to make it huge.

Answer (score 4):

You are allowed to select a single evolution if you choose, because it mentions *you can*. which is giving you an option. **However**, you can't make an eidolon huge with this spell. In [Evolution Surge, Lesser](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/evolution-surge/) it states:

> You can grant an evolution that allows you to spend additional evolution points to upgrade that evolution . **This spell cannot be used to grant an upgrade to an evolution that the eidolon already possesses.**

(emphasis mine). While *greater* states:

> This spell functions as lesser evolution surge (see above), except that you can grant any two evolutions **whose total cost does not exceed 6 evolution points**.

(emphasis mine). The [*Large (Ex)*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/summoner-unchained/eidolons-unchained/#TOC-4-Point-Evolutions) is a 4-point evolution that mentions

> If 6 additional evolution points are spent, the eidolon instead becomes Huge.

This is now a 10 point evolution, and evolution surge prevents you from upgrading an existing *Large* evolution to spend the additional 6 points to make it huge.

You could though, as an example, take *Fast Healing (Su)*, if the eidolon doesn't already have it, which is a 4 point evolution, and grants additional healing for every 2 points beyond the mandatory 4, so by spending 6 you would get 2 fast healing instead of 1. That would be a single 6 point evolution, which would be valid to take. (I see a couple other instances where you could do something like this, but *Fast Healing (Su)* is just right above the *Large (Ex)* we were just looking at, so made a decent example).

Comment: I disagree. The spell clearly states that it can be used to upgrade evolutions it has, but it cant get the same evolution. So the spell cant be used to gain extra limbs, but can be used to become larger.

Comment: It can be used to become *Large*, but not any larger than that. And it could be used to gain an evolution and upgrade it, like using 4 points to obtain magical *flight* or a constitution poison, but not upgrade an evolution the eidolon already has, such as large becoming huge by paying an additional 6 points.